# Emacs 29 docstring single quote escaping rules, compiler level event?

Tags: string, doc-strings

I've seen the following warning from the Emacs 29 compiler:

```
In s-format:
s.el:614:2: Warning: docstring has wrong usage of unescaped single quotes (use
    \= or different quoting)
```

I haven't been able to find this documented.  Can anyone help?

(EDIT: I am specifically trying to find out when/why it was decided to be a compiler level event.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation is:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Keys in Documentation`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Text Quoting Style`

In short, the `text-quoting-style` feature introduced in Emacs 25 made
it impossible to use certain characters in docstrings (most notably
the normal ascii apostrophes which are so very prevalent in lisp)
without escaping them with `\=` (which is `"\\="` in the double-quoted read syntax for strings), as otherwise they are liable to be
replaced by different quote characters at render time.

So to write a docstring containing an apostrope, you must use this:

```
"\\='"
```

instead of simply

```
"'"
```

It's a compiler warning because it very likely indicates that the docstring displays invalid lisp code.  (Some people have argued for it to be relegated to checkdoc, but that would dramatically limit the number of people who notice these bugs, so I suspect it'll remain a byte-compilation warning.)

If you're seeing these in third-party packages, submit bug reports.

Tangentially, you can ensure you're never affected by such bugs by using the old-style docstring rendering, by setting `text-quoting-style` to `grave`.

Comment: Thank you, I was more interested to know when the warning became a compiler level event. (marking correct due to the original wording of the question.)

Comment: It became a byte-compilation warning in Emacs 29 (unstable at time of writing, but I think the warning is likely to remain as such for stable releases).  Search for `\=` in the NEWS file.

Comment: Well, that's very poorly designed… I am looking at such warnings in `annalist.el` code, and they all come from code examples. Replacing every quote with a `\\='` hurts readability, so I don't even want to fix them. To make things worse, Emacs doesn't provide a way to disable specifically this problematic warning about quotes, you can only disable all docstring warnings entirely… With that said, I recommend to deal with this warning by putting a `(setq byte-compile-warnings '(not docstrings))` to your init file.

Comment: Hi-Angel: Sorry, but that is a terrible "recommendation".  Code examples are *broken* if those quotes are left un-escaped -- such cases represent *bugs in the code which should be fixed*.  The only crucial thing for "readability" is what appears in the \*Help\* buffer when the docstring is rendered, and by ignoring those bugs you will see the wrong code in the \*Help\* buffer.

Comment: If annalist.el is a program you wrote and no one else is ever going to use it, then you can of course do whatever you want.  If it's code you wrote and you're sharing it with others, it's wrong not to use the correct syntax.  If it's code someone else wrote, you should submit a bug report for this (if one does not already exist).

Comment: FWIW these quoting requirements were very controversial when they were introduced and the discussions were lengthy and heated.  A great many people didn't like the change (myself included).  However it's water under the bridge at this point, and I'm pretty certain no one would have any appetite for revisiting the subject.  It is what it is (and has been for many years), and not liking it won't change anything.  Docstrings simply have to adhere to these rules in order to be correct for all users.

Comment: @phils thank you for explanation! The `annalist.el` is not my project, it's on my system due to being a dep for `evil-collection` mode. I wouldn't say the code examples are broken, because they render fine in `C-h f …`. Well, aside of the single apostrophe looking fancy due to being a unicode char. So I don't see much motivation to fix that besides just seeing the warning, which IMO is not really on point. P.S.: please use `@` so I get notification 

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Rendering as a fancy unicode char *is* the broken-ness.  Copying such code and attempting to evaluate it will produce errors, because a fancy unicode quote character is *not* the `quote` syntax recognised by the lisp reader.  If it's not an ascii apostrophe `'` then it won't work (and users who don't already understand the issue are liable to get incredibly confused by it, because (a) they copied it directly from the \*Help\* buffer, and (b) depending on their fonts they may not even be able to see the difference).  A bug report for the annalist.el maintainer is very much warranted.

Answer (score 4):

## From Emacs 29 `etc/NEWS`

*(slightly paraphrased)*

Byte compilation will now warn about some quoting mistakes in `docstrings`.
When writing code that contains the `'` character `(APOSTROPHE)`,
that quote character has to be escaped to avoid Emacs displaying it as
`’` `(LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK)`, which would make code examples like
this invalid:

```
(setq foo '(1 2 3))
```

Emacs will now warn during byte compilation if it sees something like
that, and also warn about when using `RIGHT/LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` directly.  In both these cases, if these characters
should really be present in the `docstring`, they should be quoted with
`\=`

---

Refer to Phil's answer and https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Keys-in-Documentation for extended  usage info for `\=`